# Unable to run babel command on CLI

Tags: javascript, babeljs, flowtype

I am trying to install `flow` as docs suggests https://flow.org/en/docs/install/ It requires to install `babel-cli` to run `babel`.

I installed `babel-cli` using below command https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

> npm install --save-dev babel-cli

```
> npm install --save-dev babel-cli
todo-app@0.1.0 D:\React JS\todo-app
`-- babel-cli@6.24.1

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.0.17 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React JS\todo-app\node_modules\acorn-dynamic-import\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React JS\todo-app\node_modules\create-hmac\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React JS\todo-app\node_modules\create-hash\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React JS\todo-app\node_modules\diffie-hellman\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React JS\todo-app\node_modules\pbkdf2\package.json'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

When I run `babel` command then it gives me an error 'babel' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

### Update

It is because "local binaries probably aren't found because the local ./node_modules/.bin is not in $PATH" - but do you think Is it good to add `node_modules/.bin` of all projects in a $PATH ? or Is there any alternative to do ?

PS: I am on windows machine.

Comment: Which OS? Try installing it global? `npm install --global babel-cli`

Comment: @mkaatman I am trying on windows, https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/ docs says "you should not install it globally"

Comment: Yeah but you're on windows. All bets are off.

Comment: @mkaatman babel doesn't work on windows ?

Comment: Try: `./node_modules/.bin/babel`

Comment: @mkaatman It is probably "local binaries probably aren't found because the local ./node_modules/.bin is not in $PATH" - but do you think Is it good to add for all projects in a $PATH ? or Is there any alternative to do ?

Comment: @mkaatman Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I do not unfortunately. You could open a bounty and I bet you'd get a good response.

Comment: Did you also run: `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-flow`? Where are you trying to execute Babel from? Project root? Did you also try `flow-remove-types` as an alternative to Babel?

Comment: @J.Titus Yep I have babel-preset-flow . Yes I am trying to execute it from project root. I have to set path `D:\ReactJS\todo-app\node_modules\.bin` to have an access of `babel` but of how many project I have to do this. There must be some other approach. I set in environment variable so If I set it again of different project then there will be conflict of which project babel it need to access

Comment: @J.Titus see here I was trying to setup flow for type checking but babel was creating an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44581652/yarn-run-babel-src-d-lib-babel-src-d-lib-d-doesnt-exist-lib-doesn

Comment: I had the same error msg, and for me the solution was as simple as just running `npm install` after changing the `package.json` file. After that, the `babel` command was apparently very legit. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `babel` script in your **package.json**

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "babel": "babel"
}
```

Then you can run babel with:

```sh
npm run babel
```

If you want to pass arguments when running from the command line, separate them from the command with `--` [(more info)](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3494).  For example:

```sh
npm run babel -- --help
```

This way you run the version of babel specified in `package.json` and installed by `npm` and you do not need to edit your PATH variable.

Note: This is the [same approach as `flow` recommends for itself in its installation instructions,](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/). (Switch it to `npm` at the top then scroll down to "Setup Flow")

Comment: I need to execute this command `babel src/ -d lib/` can you suggest. I tried with this `npm run babel src/ -d lib/` but this is not generating output files in lib directory. When I set babel in environment path then it works

Comment: @Williams see the note above about passing arguments.  You will need `npm run babel -- src/ -d lib/`.  For what its worth, in most cases I would probably define a new script `"compile": "babel src/ -d lib/"` rather than take the approach of passing arguments.

Comment: @NSharma , plz specify how you "set babel in environment path"?