# yarn run babel src/ -- -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/ -d doesn't exist. lib/ doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, flowtype

I am following steps of https://flow.org/en/docs/install/ When I am running below command then it is giving me an error.

> yarn run babel src/ -- -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/

```
yarn run babel src/ -- -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/
yarn run v0.23.3
$ "D:\ReactJS\todo-app\node_modules\.bin\babel" src/ -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/
-d doesn't exist. lib/ doesn't exist
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.48.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "flow",
        "react",
        "es2015"
    ]
}
```

### Update

I resolved above error by executing this command `yarn run babel src/ -d lib/` but now getting below error. BTW it is running perfect on my web browser.

```
> yarn run babel src/ -d lib/
yarn run v0.23.3
$ "D:\ReactJS\todo-app\node_modules\.bin\babel" src/
SyntaxError: src/App.js: Unexpected token (42:13)
  40 |   }
  41 |
> 42 |   handleOpen = () => {
     |              ^
  43 |     this.setState({ open: true });
  44 |   };
  45 |
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

App.js

```
/* @flow */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import FloatingActionButton from "material-ui/FloatingActionButton";
import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";
import * as strings from "./Strings";
import * as colors from "./Colors";
import styles from "./Styles";
import ContentAdd from "material-ui/svg-icons/content/add";
import Dialog from "material-ui/Dialog";
import FlatButton from "material-ui/FlatButton";
import * as injectTapEventPlugin from "react-tap-event-plugin";
import TextField from "material-ui/TextField";
import { List, ListItem } from "material-ui/List";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { addTodo } from "./actions/index";
import * as actions from "./actions/index";

const AppBarTest = () =>
  <AppBar
    title={strings.app_name}
    iconClassNameRight="muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more"
    style={{ backgroundColor: colors.blue_color }}
  />;

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    injectTapEventPlugin();
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
      todos: [],
      notetext: ""
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleCreateNote = () => {
    let todos = [...this.state.todos];
    todos.push({
      id: todos.length,
      text: this.state.notetext,
      completed: false
    });
    this.setState({ todos: todos }, () => {
      // setState is async, so this is callback
    });
    this.props.addTodo(this.state.notetext);
    this.handleClose();
  };

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  _renderTodos() {
    return this.props.todos.map(event => {
      return (
        <ListItem
          primaryText={event.text}
          key={event.id}
          style={{ width: "100%", textAlign: "center" }}
          onTouchTap={this._handleListItemClick.bind(this, event)}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  _handleListItemClick(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <div>
          <AppBarTest />
          <FloatingActionButton
            style={styles.fab}
            backgroundColor={colors.blue_color}
            onTouchTap={this.handleOpen}
          >
            <ContentAdd />
          </FloatingActionButton>
          <Dialog
            open={this.state.open}
            onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
            title={strings.dialog_create_note_title}
          >
            <TextField
              name="notetext"
              hintText="Note"
              style={{ width: "48%", float: "left", height: 48 }}
              defaultValue={this.state.noteVal}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={ev => {
                if (ev.key === "Enter") {
                  this.handleCreateNote();
                  ev.preventDefault();
                }
              }}
            />

            <div
              style={{
                width: "4%",
                height: "1",
                float: "left",
                visibility: "hidden"
              }}
            />

            <FlatButton
              label={strings.create_note}
              style={{ width: "48%", height: 48, float: "left" }}
              onTouchTap={this.handleCreateNote}
            />
          </Dialog>

          <List style={{ margin: 8 }}>
            {this._renderTodos()}
          </List>

        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

Comment: can you provide dir structure of your project? did you install  **First install babel-cli and babel-preset-flow with either Yarn or npm.**

Comment: @MehulJoshi See it http://imgur.com/a/7W5Bu I have installed babel-cli and babel-preset-flow see https://pastebin.com/SidfGh2V

Comment: can you create this 2 dir? in the folder. **lib/babel   lib/**  it seems like yarn is not able to find lib dir. create this dir and run command with sudo or with admin permission in case of windows.

Comment: @MehulJoshi I have created `lib/babel` directory, now I am getting `yarn run babel src/ -- -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/
yarn run v0.23.3
$ "D:\ReactJS\todo-app\node_modules\.bin\babel" src/ -d lib/babel -- src/ -d lib/
-d doesn't exist
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.`

Comment: @MehulJoshi Do you have any idea what "-d" means here ?

Comment: yep, it's destination, can you check if you have bable installed, and properly available in the path?\

Comment: @MehulJoshi yep I set it in a environment variable in PATH so I am able to access babel

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: @MehulJoshi Nope

Comment: can you create git repo and share with me? I will do the integration part and push the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got it work, I will go with the second error.

You should install [`preset-stage-0`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/) from Babel and [`transform-runtime`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/)

and add it to your `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "flow",
        "react",
        "es2015",
        "stage-0"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-runtime"]
}
```

As they mention on their web page

> This preset includes the following plugins:
>
> **transform-do-expressions
>
>   transform-function-bind**
>
> And all plugins from presets:
>
> **preset-stage-1
>
>   preset-stage-2
>
>   preset-stage-3**

So you have a better es6 support for some features that are not included in the base Babel transpiler

And last but not less important `preset-state-2` contains [`transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which is actually the error that you describe in your updated question.

## Update


As we were having a tracking of your problem, we realized that `yarn run` is not working as expected with the Babel CLI.
Instead is better to use `npm` and add a script to the package.json:

```
"scripts": { 
  "build": "babel src/ -d lib/"
}
```

and then:

`npm run build`

Comment: See this is output of `yarn run babel src/ -d lib/` https://pastebin.com/a9GrdXcZ what does it means ? it has not created any lib folder and build kinda

Comment: Did you install the plugin that I mentioned?

Comment: Yep. This solved my error which I have in my question, but now this is the output of that command https://pastebin.com/a9GrdXcZ

Comment: There are not errors! but you said that the output file is not created?

Comment: Yep, it should generate some output file right ? as far as i know it should create lib in root directory and generate output file. but it is not creating lib directory and no output file. I tried this command using administrative right on cmd

Comment: Try installing the `transform-runtime` plugin from Babel, and update your `.babelrc` file with `"plugins": ["transform-runtime"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147142/discussion-between-joseapl-and-williams).